# Redirecting to another page not working in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using `jquery 1.6.2` and this is my ajax call function:

```
function remoteCall(sUrl, sQueryStr)
{     
    $.ajax({
        type:    "POST",
        url:     sUrl,
        data:    sQueryStr,
        async:   false,
        success: function(response){
            var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
            if( obj.status === "N" ){
                alert('You have already submitted the Form');   
                window.location= 'www.example.com';
            }
            if( obj.status === "S" || obj.status === "Y"){
                alert('Thank you for sumbitting the Form');
                window.location= 'www.abc.com';
            }               
        }
```

This `window.location` is not working?

Also when in following code `window.location` is working in IE and FF but not in Chrome:

```
function remoteCall1(sUrl, sQueryStr,div)
 {
     $.post(sUrl,  sQueryStr ,
         function(response){
          if(div !=''){
             $('#'+div).html(unescape(response));
             return true;
             }else{
             window.location= "www.google.com";
             }
         });
 }

    }); 
    // return URL_Redirect;
}
```

please help.
thanks

Comment: "Is not working" is not a good error description. This needs debugging first. Does the success callback ever fire`What does `obj.status` contain?

Comment: have you tried debugging and stepping through the callback method in Chrome's java console to see if the line with window.location gets hit? as far as I am concerned window.location is perfectly fine, in chrome as well as all browsers

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
 window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Also, as Pekka noted, be sure that this is the part that's not really working. Use your JS console to check wheter the statement gets run or not.

Comment: used already but its not working.. :(

Comment: The problem must be somewhere else then, this code works fine in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

remove the "window."

```
    location= "www.google.com";
```

Comment: really its working for me. i am using jquery v1.6.2